# Node of Linked List in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I was starting on linked list program in java but there was a problem struck on my mind that if pointers are not allowed in java then how are linked list created in java.(I am familiar with linked list in C++). I have got this class `LinkedList`to create the node

```
public class LinkedList { 

Node head; // head of list 

// Linked list Node. 
// This inner class is made static 
// so that main() can access it 
static class Node { 

    int data; 
    Node next; 

    // Constructor 
    Node(int d) 
    { 
        data = d; 
        next = null; 
    } 
}
```

The code works but i am not getting as how the reference is being created at the next node.

Comment: This code doesn't create any references; it declares two fields of reference type `Node head;` and `Node next;`, and the `Node` constructor assigns `null` to one of those fields.

Comment: FYI all Objects in Java exist in the heap (okay, or in the string constants pool) and the stack accesses them through references, which is another name for a pointer

Comment: The difference between Java and C for example, is that pointers in Java are strongly typed.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/java-different-types-of-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit pointer arithmetics are not available for the Java programmer, pointers are everywhere in Java too.

Actually, Java references are pointers, they were named like that after a series of bad decisions from the developers at Sun, hence creating this great confusion.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1
(See second sentence)

Also, another great source of confusion is comparing Java references to references (or aliases) from C++ (or many more non-JVM based programming languages). 
They are nothing alike, Java has got pointers named references and C++ has got both pointers and references.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you reference an object in Java, you use a reference (a rough approximation of a `shared_ptr`). Only primitive types (like `int`) are value types in Java, everything else is internally built on references. So no copy constructors are needed, and no special "pointer type" is needed.

So if you declare `Node next`, `next` is a reference to an object, not a copy of it.

A reasonable linked list could like so:

```java
class Node<T> {
  T value;
  Node<T> next;

  public Node(T value, Node<T> next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

Node<String> list = new Node("This", new Node("is", new Node("it.", null)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `setNext` method node

```
public void setNext(Node n) {
  next = n;
}
```

Then

```
Node n1 = new Node(1);
Node n2 = new Node(2);
n1.setNext(n2);
```